# Check if a given modern team site has a connected group or not

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom, pnp

Is it possible through CSOM to check if given site has a connected group or not?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to check the `GroupId` property as below:

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("siteUrl"))
{   
    // authenticate
    clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site, s => s.GroupId);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

    var groupId = clientContext.Site.GroupId;
    if (context.Site.GroupId != Guid.Empty){
        // Group site, do something
    }
    else
    {
        // Not a group site, do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Gautam Sheth shared a good method. And i noticed that you have tagged this issue with pnp. If you want to get it via pnp powershell, you can try below cmdlets:

```
Get-PnPProperty $(Get-PnPSite) -Property GroupId
```

And for rest api, it's:

```
_api/web?$select=AllProperties&$expand=AllProperties
```

[image]

BR